# How can I add text-decoration to my Angular Material mat-form-field?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular-material-6

### My question: how can I add text-decoration to my Angular Material mat-form-field (e.g. `text-decoration: line-through`)?

I'm new to using the Angular Material library and am finding that in order to change almost anything, you have to either

disable ViewEncapsulation

```
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  ...
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

or

use ng-deep

```
::ng-deep .class {
    property: value;
}
```

So I disabled ViewEncapsulation and tried the two following ways of doing it, but neither works:

```
.mat-input {
    text-decoration: line-through !important;
}

.mat-form-field {
    text-decoration: line-through !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to set the style on the `mat-input-element` class in order for the line-through property to apply.

```
.mat-input-element {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

You can find a sample StackBlitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-fdubu9

Comment: Thanks. I'd love to know how you found this out. Looking through the Angular material docs, I don't see the `mat-input-element` class mentioned anywhere.

Comment: I just inspected the element and tried adding the styles in the browser. It does not seem to work when added to a parent element. (Probably being overridden by a default style rule)